# How to save SVG for using with snapsvg,js?

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

```
var snap = Snap('#snap'),
    snapCode = "M42.1596297,13.586522 L48.3696297,16.220522 C49.1016297,16.532522 49.0766297,17.026522 48.3106297,17.323522 L41.8376297,19.850522 C41.0716297,20.147522 39.8576297,20.137522 39.1206297,19.826522 L32.9156297,17.191522 C32.1786297,16.884522 32.2026297,16.386522 32.9696297,16.088522 L39.4426297,13.567522 C40.2086297,13.264522 41.4286297,13.279522 42.1596297,13.586522 L42.1596297,13.586522 Z M31.0686297,17.913522 L37.2736297,20.547522 C38.0096297,20.854522 37.9856297,21.352522 37.2186297,21.650522 L30.7456297,24.171522 C29.9796297,24.474522 28.7606297,24.464522 28.0286297,24.151522 L21.8186297,21.517522 C21.0826297,21.209522 21.1106297,20.712522 21.8776297,20.414522 L28.3506297,17.893522 C29.1166297,17.591522 30.3316297,17.601522 31.0686297,17.913522 L31.0686297,17.913522 Z M20.4246297,13.406522 L26.6336297,16.035522 C27.3656297,16.347522 27.3416297,16.841522 26.5746297,17.139522 L20.1016297,19.665522 C19.3356297,19.963522 18.1206297,19.952522 17.3846297,19.641522 L11.1756297,17.011522 C10.4446297,16.699522 10.4676297,16.206522 11.2336297,15.905522 L17.7066297,13.383522 C18.4726297,13.083522 19.6876297,13.094522 20.4246297,13.406522 L20.4246297,13.406522 Z M9.7806297,8.89452195 L15.9896297,11.523522 C16.7216297,11.835522 16.6976297,12.333522 15.9316297,12.630522 L9.4586297,15.151522 C8.6926297,15.449522 7.4786297,15.439522 6.7416297,15.128522 L0.536629704,12.498522 C-0.199370296,12.186522 -0.175370296,11.693522 0.590629704,11.395522 L7.0636297,8.86952195 C7.8286297,8.57252195 9.0436297,8.58152195 9.7806297,8.89452195 L9.7806297,8.89452195 Z M31.5166297,9.07952195 L37.7266297,11.708522 C38.4626297,12.020522 38.4336297,12.513522 37.6676297,12.815522 L31.1996297,15.336522 C30.4326297,15.634522 29.2136297,15.624522 28.4816297,15.312522 L22.2726297,12.682522 C21.5356297,12.370522 21.5646297,11.878522 22.3306297,11.576522 L28.7996297,9.05452195 C29.5656297,8.75752195 30.7846297,8.76752195 31.5166297,9.07952195 L31.5166297,9.07952195 Z M20.8776297,4.56752195 L27.0826297,7.20152195 C27.8186297,7.50952195 27.7946297,8.00652195 27.0296297,8.30552195 L20.5556297,10.826522 C19.7896297,11.129522 18.5706297,11.113522 17.8386297,10.806522 L11.6296297,8.17152195 C10.8976297,7.85952195 10.9216297,7.36652195 11.6886297,7.06952195 L18.1616297,4.54252195 C18.9266297,4.24552195 20.1416297,4.25552195 20.8776297,4.56752195 L20.8776297,4.56752195 Z M53.2576297,9.26552195 L59.4626297,11.894522 C60.1986297,12.206522 60.1746297,12.699522 59.4086297,12.997522 L52.9346297,15.523522 C52.1686297,15.821522 50.9556297,15.811522 50.2176297,15.499522 L44.0086297,12.870522 C43.2766297,12.558522 43.3006297,12.060522 44.0676297,11.763522 L50.5406297,9.24152195 C51.3066297,8.94352195 52.5216297,8.95252195 53.2576297,9.26552195 L53.2576297,9.26552195 Z M42.6146297,4.75252195 L48.8246297,7.38252195 C49.5556297,7.69452195 49.5316297,8.18752195 48.7656297,8.48852195 L42.2926297,11.010522 C41.5256297,11.307522 40.3116297,11.297522 39.5746297,10.985522 L33.3646297,8.35652195 C32.6336297,8.04452195 32.6576297,7.55152195 33.4236297,7.25352195 L39.8976297,4.72752195 C40.6626297,4.43052195 41.8776297,4.44152195 42.6146297,4.75252195 L42.6146297,4.75252195 Z M31.9706297,0.240521954 L38.1796297,2.87452195 C38.9156297,3.18152195 38.8876297,3.67952195 38.1206297,3.97652195 L31.6476297,6.49852195 C30.8816297,6.80152195 29.6676297,6.79152195 28.9306297,6.47852195 L22.7256297,3.84452195 C21.9896297,3.53652195 22.0136297,3.03952195 22.7796297,2.74152195 L29.2526297,0.219521954 C30.0196297,-0.0814780463 31.2396297,-0.0714780463 31.9706297,0.240521954 L31.9706297,0.240521954 Z",
    snapCodeHover = "M42.926,15.289 L49.036,17.88 C49.757,18.188 49.732,18.673 48.978,18.966 L42.609,21.452 C41.855,21.745 40.66,21.734 39.935,21.428 L33.83,18.836 C33.105,18.533 33.129,18.044 33.883,17.751 L40.252,15.27 C41.006,14.972 42.206,14.987 42.926,15.289 L42.926,15.289 Z M31.051,20.027 L37.156,22.619 C37.881,22.921 37.857,23.411 37.103,23.704 L30.734,26.186 C29.98,26.483 28.78,26.473 28.06,26.166 L21.95,23.574 C21.225,23.271 21.254,22.782 22.008,22.489 L28.378,20.008 C29.131,19.709 30.326,19.719 31.051,20.027 L31.051,20.027 Z M20.098,15.112 L26.208,17.699 C26.928,18.007 26.903,18.491 26.15,18.784 L19.78,21.27 C19.026,21.563 17.831,21.553 17.106,21.246 L10.996,18.659 C10.276,18.351 10.3,17.867 11.053,17.569 L17.423,15.088 C18.178,14.794 19.373,14.804 20.098,15.112 L20.098,15.112 Z M9.624,10.192 L15.734,12.779 C16.454,13.087 16.43,13.576 15.677,13.869 L9.307,16.35 C8.553,16.643 7.358,16.633 6.633,16.326 L0.528,13.739 C-0.197,13.431 -0.173,12.947 0.581,12.654 L6.95,10.168 C7.704,9.874 8.9,9.884 9.624,10.192 L9.624,10.192 Z M31.492,10.373 L37.602,12.96 C38.327,13.268 38.298,13.753 37.544,14.05 L31.18,16.532 C30.426,16.825 29.226,16.814 28.506,16.508 L22.396,13.92 C21.671,13.613 21.7,13.129 22.453,12.831 L28.818,10.35 C29.573,10.057 30.773,10.067 31.492,10.373 L31.492,10.373 Z M20.544,4.974 L26.649,7.566 C27.374,7.869 27.349,8.358 26.596,8.651 L20.226,11.132 C19.472,11.43 18.272,11.415 17.552,11.112 L11.442,8.52 C10.722,8.213 10.746,7.728 11.5,7.435 L17.869,4.949 C18.624,4.656 19.82,4.666 20.544,4.974 L20.544,4.974 Z M53.366,10.076 L59.47,12.663 C60.196,12.971 60.171,13.455 59.418,13.748 L53.048,16.234 C52.295,16.527 51.1,16.517 50.375,16.21 L44.264,13.623 C43.544,13.315 43.569,12.826 44.323,12.533 L50.692,10.052 C51.446,9.759 52.641,9.769 53.366,10.076 L53.366,10.076 Z M42.893,5.156 L49.003,7.743 C49.723,8.051 49.699,8.535 48.945,8.833 L42.576,11.314 C41.822,11.607 40.627,11.597 39.902,11.29 L33.792,8.703 C33.071,8.395 33.096,7.911 33.85,7.618 L40.219,5.132 C40.973,4.839 42.168,4.849 42.893,5.156 L42.893,5.156 Z M31.94,0.237 L38.049,2.829 C38.774,3.131 38.745,3.621 37.991,3.914 L31.622,6.395 C30.868,6.692 29.673,6.683 28.948,6.375 L22.843,3.783 C22.118,3.48 22.142,2.991 22.896,2.698 L29.266,0.217 C30.02,-0.081 31.219,-0.071 31.94,0.237 L31.94,0.237 Z",
    snapPath = snap.path(snapCode);

$('#snap').hover(function () {
    snapPath.animate({d: snapCodeHover}, 1000, mina.bounce);
    }, function () {
    snapPath.animate({d: snapCode}, 1000, mina.bounce);
});

var snap2 = Snap('#snap2'),
    snap2code = "M330.93 398.85l12.73 5.4c1.5.64 1.45 1.65-.12 2.26l-13.27 5.18c-1.57.61-4.06.59-5.57-.05l-12.72-5.4c-1.51-.63-1.46-1.65.11-2.26l13.27-5.17c1.57-.62 4.07-.59 5.57.04zm-22.74 8.87l12.72 5.4c1.51.63 1.46 1.65-.11 2.26l-13.27 5.17c-1.57.62-4.07.6-5.57-.04l-12.73-5.4c-1.51-.63-1.45-1.65.12-2.26l13.27-5.17c1.57-.62 4.06-.6 5.57.04zm-21.82-9.24l12.73 5.39c1.5.64 1.45 1.65-.12 2.26l-13.27 5.18c-1.57.61-4.06.59-5.57-.05l-12.73-5.39c-1.5-.64-1.45-1.65.12-2.27l13.27-5.17c1.57-.61 4.06-.59 5.57.05zm-21.82-9.25l12.73 5.39c1.5.64 1.45 1.66-.12 2.27l-13.27 5.17c-1.57.61-4.06.59-5.57-.05l-12.72-5.39c-1.51-.64-1.46-1.65.11-2.26l13.27-5.18c1.57-.61 4.06-.59 5.57.05zm44.56.38l12.73 5.39c1.51.64 1.45 1.65-.12 2.27l-13.26 5.17c-1.57.61-4.07.59-5.57-.05l-12.73-5.39c-1.51-.64-1.45-1.65.12-2.27l13.26-5.17c1.57-.61 4.07-.59 5.57.05zm-21.81-9.25l12.72 5.4c1.51.63 1.46 1.65-.11 2.26l-13.27 5.17c-1.57.62-4.07.59-5.57-.04l-12.73-5.4c-1.5-.64-1.45-1.65.12-2.26l13.27-5.18c1.57-.61 4.06-.59 5.57.05zm66.38 9.63l12.72 5.39c1.51.64 1.46 1.65-.11 2.26l-13.27 5.18c-1.57.61-4.06.59-5.57-.05l-12.73-5.39c-1.5-.64-1.45-1.66.12-2.27l13.27-5.17c1.57-.61 4.06-.59 5.57.05zm-21.82-9.25l12.73 5.39c1.5.64 1.45 1.65-.12 2.27l-13.27 5.17c-1.57.61-4.06.59-5.57-.05l-12.73-5.39c-1.5-.64-1.45-1.65.12-2.26l13.27-5.18c1.57-.61 4.06-.59 5.57.05zm-21.82-9.25l12.73 5.4c1.51.63 1.45 1.65-.12 2.26l-13.27 5.17c-1.57.62-4.06.6-5.57-.04l-12.72-5.4c-1.51-.63-1.46-1.65.11-2.26l13.27-5.17c1.57-.62 4.07-.6 5.57.04z",
    snap2codeHover = "M332.9 400.4l12.7 5.4c1.5.6 1.5 1.6-.1 2.3l-13.3 5.2c-1.6.6-4.1.6-5.6 0l-12.7-5.4c-1.5-.6-1.5-1.6.1-2.3l13.3-5.2c1.6-.7 4.1-.7 5.6 0zm-24.7 9.8l12.7 5.4c1.5.6 1.5 1.6-.1 2.3l-13.3 5.2c-1.6.6-4.1.6-5.6 0l-12.7-5.4c-1.5-.6-1.5-1.6.1-2.3l13.3-5.2c1.6-.6 4.1-.6 5.6 0zm-22.8-10.2l12.7 5.4c1.5.6 1.5 1.6-.1 2.3l-13.3 5.2c-1.6.6-4.1.6-5.6 0l-12.7-5.4c-1.5-.6-1.5-1.6.1-2.3l13.3-5.2c1.6-.7 4.1-.7 5.6 0zm-21.9-10.3l12.7 5.4c1.5.6 1.5 1.7-.1 2.3l-13.3 5.2c-1.6.6-4.1.6-5.6 0l-12.7-5.4c-1.5-.6-1.5-1.6.1-2.3l13.3-5.2c1.6-.6 4.1-.6 5.6 0zm45.6.4l12.7 5.4c1.5.6 1.5 1.6-.1 2.3l-13.3 5.2c-1.6.6-4.1.6-5.6 0l-12.7-5.4c-1.5-.6-1.5-1.6.1-2.3l13.3-5.2c1.6-.6 4.1-.6 5.6 0zm-22.8-11.2l12.7 5.4c1.5.6 1.5 1.6-.1 2.3l-13.3 5.2c-1.6.6-4.1.6-5.6 0l-12.7-5.4c-1.5-.6-1.5-1.6.1-2.3l13.3-5.2c1.6-.7 4.1-.7 5.6 0zm68.4 10.6l12.7 5.4c1.5.6 1.5 1.6-.1 2.3l-13.3 5.2c-1.6.6-4.1.6-5.6 0l-12.7-5.4c-1.5-.6-1.5-1.7.1-2.3l13.3-5.2c1.6-.7 4.1-.6 5.6 0zm-21.8-10.3l12.7 5.4c1.5.6 1.5 1.6-.1 2.3l-13.3 5.2c-1.6.6-4.1.6-5.6 0l-12.7-5.4c-1.5-.6-1.5-1.6.1-2.3l13.3-5.2c1.6-.6 4.1-.6 5.6 0zm-22.9-10.2l12.7 5.4c1.5.6 1.5 1.6-.1 2.3l-13.3 5.2c-1.6.6-4.1.6-5.6 0l-12.7-5.4c-1.5-.6-1.5-1.6.1-2.3l13.3-5.2c1.6-.7 4.1-.6 5.6 0z",
    snap2path = snap2.path(snap2code);

$('#snap2').hover(function () {
    snap2path.animate({d: snap2codeHover}, 1000, mina.bounce);
    }, function () {
    snap2path.animate({d: snap2code}, 1000, mina.bounce);
});

var snap3 = Snap('#snap3'),
    snap3code = "M50,50H0V0h50V50z",
    snap3codeHover = "M50,25c0,13.8-11.2,25-25,25S0,38.8,0,25S11.2,0,25,0S50,11.2,50,25z",
    snap3path = snap3.path(snap3code);

$('#snap3').hover(function () {
    snap3path.animate({d: snap3codeHover}, 1000, mina.bounce);
    }, function () {
    snap3path.animate({d: snap3code}, 1000, mina.bounce);
});
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frbt1eu9/3/)

I have an icon (1st block in example) that transforms when hover using snapsvg.js ( http://snapsvg.io/ ) and it works fine. Path for this icon include in js code.

I don't know who and how made this, but now i must change this icon by another.

I have two svg files in site source. It's two condition of this icon.
Code in Path in that svg files if differ from Path in js.
I put this code to 2nd block in example, and it's not work.

I create by Adobe Illustrator CC simple icon - square that must transform to round. It's work, but bad (3rd block). Saving with different parametrs don't help. Icon don't centering, don't scale correct, don't have code like first example.

How to save path from Illustrator for using with snapsvg.js?

Answer (score 1):

Solved

1. No technical difference between Path in that script and path from Illustrator.
   If you need to get Path like Path in script - export svg from Photoshop.
2. Important right viewbox for avoid problems with display. More information: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/